# How do I get the sums of digits of the negative large number in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
sumOfDigitsPosNeg x =
    if x == 0 then 0
    else if x < 0 then sumOfDigitsPosNeg ((-1)*x `div` 10) + mod ((-1)*x) 10 
    else sumOfDigitsPosNeg (x `div` 10) + mod x 10
```

I've tried with these code, but if the input is more than one digit, the output is wrong. I'm just confused how to convert the negative numbers into positive. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [`abs`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/abs_f.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`abs`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/abs_f.html) this is quite easy. We just operate on the absolute value of the number input.

```
sumDigits :: Integral t => t -> t
sumDigits 0 = 0
sumDigits n = a `mod` 10 + sumDigits (a `div` 10)
    where a = abs n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a helper `go` function that will only retrieve the absolute value. We thus call `go` with the [**`abs :: Num a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:abs) of the item:

```
sumOfDigitsPosNeg :: Integral a => a -> a
sumOfDigitsPosNeg = go . abs
    where go 0 = 0
          go n = r + go q
              where (q, r) = quotRem n 10
```